# Failed to create connection

Tags: kameleo

When we start a profile, the browser starts but shortly after it terminates.

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Application.Services.ProfileLifetimeHandler.ProfileLifetimeHandlerException: Failed to start profile.
---> PuppeteerSharp.ProcessException: Failed to create connection
---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The proxy tunnel request to proxy
```

For the profile not to terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been observed on Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter. If you are behind a proxy, make sure your proxy settings are configured correctly. The error is related to the inability to establish a connection through the proxy. Double-check your proxy settings in your application configuration.

Furthermore, I'd also recommend checking the following article for more information: https://help.kameleo.io/hc/en-us/articles/12330096749724-Failed-to-create-connection-Proxy-tunnel-request-to-proxy-failed-with-status-code-403